# model.find method is not returning required fields from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

The `console.log(correct.password)` is returning `undefined` whereas the if condition results in `false`.

```
app.post('/login' , async (req , res)=>
{

   const correct = data.findOne({name : req.body.name}).select({name : 0});
   if(!correct)  
   {
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid Username or 
    Password")
   };

    console.log(correct.password);

   const passcomp = compare(req , correct);
  if(!passcomp) { console.log("innnncorrect");return 

  res.status(400).send("Invalid Username or Password");}

  res.send("Successful");


});
```

I should get the password of the requested user, but the query I am receiving does not contain neither the name nor the password.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to add the `await` keyword before your query, as you are in an **async** function:

```
const correct = await data
  .findOne({ name : req.body.name })
  .select({ name : 0 });
```